# Networkx Finding communities of directed graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I am currently graphing and visualizing a directional social network. There is a statistic (modularity) in an open source visualization tool called Gephi (http://gephi.github.io/) that allows me to partition nodes by separating them into communities.

I'd like to accomplish this task (finding communities) with my graph *before* I visualize it with Gephi so that I can run various statistics on each community that the algorithm finds.

However, each community algorithm that I have found does not operate on directed graphs. I found two different algorithms to work with that won't work with diGraphs:

1. Aynaud's community algorithm based on dendograms at http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/api.html
2. NetworkX's own find k cliques at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html

This raises several questions, namely:

1. Is this a limitation of the type of community finding algorithm that I want to use?
2. If so, is Gephi using its algorithm by removing the directionality of the graph before looking for communities?
3. Are there other algorithms I should be looking for?
4. Are there other libraries where this is already solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are several algorithms in Machine Learning that classify nodes into groups.  Usually there is some data or node name that makes a node distinctive as part of one group or another.  There might be other ways to break up the nodes besides data information like the number of links (which is a type of calculated data used in the pagerank algorithm).  There are several to try based on the criteria like Support Vector machines or ensemble methods like random forests.  There is also ways to reduce the dimentionality of your data using Principle Component Analysis.  There is some excellent documentation on the scikit-learn page. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html

Comment: Assuming that I understand correctly, those methods (SVM, Random Forest Ensemble, etc.) are supervised methods that would have to be trained on a graph where each node already has a group. I did not know of a way to assign these groups in the first place.

PageRank/centrality is good for finding the "influence" of nodes, but not creating groups.

I'm looking for more of an unsupervised answer that creates groups based on network structure.

I ended up using Aynaud's community algorithm that uses dendograms to create groups of nodes.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you found something that worked for you.   I was assuming since you were using Gephi you had some way to differentiate groups.  Also SVM is both supervised and unsupervised but I wasn't sure if it could do what you wanted it to since it find the spacing between nodes and since you would need some data to "space" the nodes. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2099486/

Comment: Interesting! I never would have thought to use SVMs to partition data in an unsupervised fashion. You have opened my horizons.
Also per your suggestion, I took a long look at scikit's clustering docs (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) and found them helpful. Thanks again!